# What is causing "Unable to initialize .NET Framework / Unable to initialize OLE"?

Tags: c++, .net

During our nightly builds I am getting the following compilation errors once or twice a week on our TeamCity build agents:

```
Stdafx.cpp error C3167: Unable to initialize .NET Framework: make sure it is installed
Stdafx.cpp error C1100: unable to initialize OLE : Class does not exist.
```

If the error occurs, it seems that the build agent is unable to build any C++ application any more. Visual C++ 2012 is being used on this virtual Windows machine. The only currently known way to fix this is rebooting the machine.

The build agent was doing its job for several years without any problems. This problem started only a several weeks ago.

Comment: That sounds like an update.

Comment: Automatic windows updates are disabled on this build agent. What I am puzzling about is that it disappears after a reboot but returns after a few days.

Comment: Seems like conflict or corrupted library issue. A roll back to before when the problem started may help.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you happen to find the cause of it ? Although I haven't tried restarting the server yet, but I have tried running the build on another agent server of teamcity and it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to find the root cause. But at least the problem was not hurting any more, after switching to [cloud-based VMware agents](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+Up+TeamCity+for+VMware+vSphere+and+vCenter) which lead to rather short agent uptimes.